# Why Bootstrap Collapse doesn't display different items for each iteration?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, jinja2, bootstrap-accordion

I am iterating through a dict list in Jinjia to hide or display the dictionary's values as below:

```
{% for data_dict in data_list %}
 {% for key, data in data_dict.items() %}
     {% if data is iterable %}
     <dd>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#rel">{{ data.keys() }}</a>
        <div id="rel" class="collapse">
          {{ data.values() }}
         </div>
     </dd>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

{% endfor %}

However, for the list of key-value pairs displayed, the first pair works for the hide/display effect when I click it. But from the second one, it always displays the dictionary's first element in the dict. The href to be displayed is:

```
http://localhost:5000/np/wg#rel
```

Is that because it always refer to the first element in the dictionary even if I intend to iterate through it? But the 'data.keys()' part is right, meaning that I got a different key strings for each iteration in the outer loop. I am thinking I may need to do something like the following, but the {{ loop.index }} should refer to the FIRST 'for' loop 'data_list'. Not sure about how to do it.

```
href="#rel-{{loop.index}}
```

The boostrap references are below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I know how to do it now.

Comment: If you solved your own problem you should write an answer explaining the solution.